# Is it possible to have access to an internal function of a smart contract already deployed?

Tags: solidity, inheritance

I have a smart contract A which inheritates B :
contract A is B

In A, there is a function "test() onlyowner" calling B.otherFunction().

In B, otherFunction is just internal. Dont have the modifier onlyOwner.

I deploy A on a testnet to test.

Somebody can implements a smart contract inherating my deployed smart contract ? And so, can he call my unprotect internal function in smart contract B ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deploy a smart contract A that inherits from contract B, the internal functions of B are not directly accessible or callable by external smart contracts deployed by others. Internal functions can only be called from within the context of the contract itself and its derived contracts (such as contract A). External contracts deployed separately cannot access or invoke internal functions directly.

Here's why:

- **Access Control:** Internal functions are meant to be used within the context of the contract they are defined in and are not accessible externally. They can only be called from within the same contract or its derived contracts.
- **Encapsulation:** Solidity enforces encapsulation, meaning that functions marked as internal can only be called within the contract and its child contracts. This is a way to protect the internal logic and state of the contract from external interference.
- **Contract Inheritance:** Inheritance allows contract A to use the internal functions of contract B, but these functions are not exposed to external contracts.

However, there are a few scenarios where internal functions might be indirectly affected by external smart contracts:

- **Code within Derived Contracts:** If a contract C is deployed, which inherits from contract A (which inherits from contract B), and contract C exposes a public or external function that calls the inherited internal function from A, it can effectively invoke the internal function from B.
- **External Calls through Public Functions:** If contract A has public functions that call internal functions from B, and these public functions have vulnerabilities (e.g., lack of proper access control), it might lead to potential security risks.